# How to modify custom attribute of a product with JSON (Postman) Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, rest-api, json, postman

thank you for reading me.

Is there a way to modify a product´s custom attribute?

I´m using postman, i use JSON POST for price and stock but i can´t find the way to update a custom attribute of a product.

Can it be done inside: `{{magento_site_path}}/rest/default/V1/products/{{sku}}` ?

What would be the Body of the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is correct. However, you should use PUT request for updating product.

And in your request json, add the following part:

```
{
    "product": {
        ......
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "<code>",
                "value": "<value>"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```